# Limit cart to 1 product per attribute/type - Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

Our company sells pharmaceuticals online and by law we are limited to how much of a particular drug a customer can purchase. 
For singular products with one brand this is easily controllable through default Magento functionality, my problem arises when we have different brands of a particular drug. 
In a nutshell I can currently limit a customer to 1 pack of paracetamol from brand A but there is nothing to stop them getting another pack from brand B at the same time.

I would like to be able to check the cart for products with a particular attribute and limit them to 1 per cart. Ideally this would be when the customer clicks add to cart and the message would be displayed via the default Magento alerts that we currently have.

EDIT: I think the easiest way to solve this would be to check the SKU codes currently in the basket when adding a product to the cart. If there is a match, Throw up an error else add the item to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you but you need to modify as per your requirement. http://ceckoslab.com/magento/magento-check-if-product-is-in-cart/..

This link is to check the cart whether the same product is added or not? So modify this as per you requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can set maximum allowed quantity in cart from admin panel. System->configuration. From left tab see catalog->inventory. Set **Maximum qty allowed in shopping cart** to 1.

If you want to add check on whole cart. see this paid [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/max-cart-quantity.html)

Comment: I think MAXIMUM QTY ALLOWED IN SHOPPING CART option doesnt related to this quesion. Because he is asking for qty one based on attribute. The scenario is, users can add multiple products but not the product of same attributes.